# Rails 5 adding admin flag to users but deleted migration and

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin, rails-migrations, dbmigrate

I made a mistake in my migration file and I deleted and then tried running the migration again and now I'm getting an **activerecord::pendingmigrationerror** when I load **localhost:3000** but when I try to run `rails:db migrate` again its keeps canceling with this message:

> Jerrys-MacBook-Air:nameofapp jerryhoglen$ rails db:migrate --trace
>
> ** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
>
> ** Invoke environment (first_time)
>
> ** Execute environment
>
> ** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
>
> ** Execute db:load_config
>
> ** Execute db:migrate == 20161227120926 AddAdminFlagToUsers: migrating ============================== -- add_column(:users, :admin, :boolean, {:default=>false, :null=>false}) rails aborted! StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:  SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: admin: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "admin" boolean DEFAULT 'f' NOT NULL"

Cant figure it out! please help

Answer (score 0):

You can run `rake db:drop` then `rake db:create && rake db:migrate` to set up a new local database or insert the value `20161227120926` into the `schema_migrations` table.

Comment: If i insert the value into the schema_migrations table what do i do after that?  Im still getting an error thats theres a migration pending

Comment: Is it the same pending error? If so I would just rebuild your development database.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, I ended up just rebuilding the database but when i push to heroku im getting an error that the page wont load when logged in as the admin because of undefined method?

Comment: I'm adding my github and heroku app if someone would take a look and help me out that would be awesome. Im very new to this and feel a little lost! https://github.com/jerryhoglen/bikesiteapp2016 and https://bikesiteapp2016.herokuapp.com/